# Mongoose get elements in an array after a certain element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

`clips` is an array inside the `User` document. Each `clips` element has an `_id`. I can access the array as follows:

```
  User
      .findById(req.user._id)
      .select('clips')
      .exec((err, user) => {
      ...
```

However, I don't want to get the whole `clips` array. I want to be able to pass an `_id` somewhere in the `select()` and get all the elements in the array that are inserted after the element with said `_id`. Is this something that is possible in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

I think so! I actually do something like this by using the mongo query language. Try doing something like

`find({'_id'{$gt:req.user.id}})`.

It should look something like that!

This should find every user id made after that id.

Here's the mongooose docs on query's too if that's any help!

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: I'm trying `.select('clips').find({ '_id': { '$gt': req.body.clipId } })`. However, it doesn't seem to find anything. Am I able to use another `find()` after the `select()`?

Comment: Try using the where method perhaps? So, .where(clips) then search for $gt? 
Or perhaps $in? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/